# Hov send variable input name from loop to controler?

Tags: .net, razor-pages

I am trying to give the user a checkbox for different levels from input type radio.
For example:
Level 1 - Item1, item2
Level 2 - Item1, item2, item3
And on the client-side, everything is fine, but I don't know how to send the name ="radAnswer+@ i.Hot" to the controller. And I have to do it so that I can only check one box for each level in the loop.

Controller where it has to be:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string radAnswer)
```

Razor side:

```
            var HotCnt = ViewBag.HotCnt;
            @for (var Cnt = 0; Cnt <= HotCnt; Cnt++)
            {
                <div class="tier-backg">
                    @foreach (var i in ViewBag.get4)
                    {
                        @if (i.Hot == Cnt && i.Hot != null)
                        {
                            <input id="Radio1" type="radio" value="@i.Name" name="radAnswer+@i.Hot" />
                            <img src="@i.Icon" title="@i.Hot" class="tier-icon2" />
                            <span>@i.Name</span>
                            <br />
                        }
                    }
                    <div>
                        @for (var ic = 0; ic < ViewBag.get4.Count && ic <= Cnt; ic++)
                        {
                            var htt = ViewBag.get4[ic].Hot;

                            @if (htt == Cnt && htt != null)
                            {
                                var ndt = (T++);
                                if (ndt == Cnt)
                                {
                                    <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="Pick One" class="buy4" />
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            }//
```